# Extracting string inbetween two string patterns in R

Tags: r, regex

If I have a character vector:

```
 links <- c("http://fdsfdsfdsfsdaaa.com/t5/this/bd-p/fdsfsdfdsfscshdad/dasd",
            "http://ffdsfdddddfdf.com/t5/that/bd-p/fdsfdsfsddfjfsd")
```

I want to extract "this" and "that" knowing that they are between "t5" and "bd-p." Totally lost on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sub`:

```
sub(".*t5/(.*)/bd-p.*","\\1",links)
[1] "this" "that"
```

Comment: Really awesome! Thank you agstudy and anyone else that tried. I love this community so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lapply(regmatches(links, regexec("t5/(.*)/bd-p", links)), '[', 2)
[[1]]
[1] "this"

[[2]]
[1] "that"
```

`regexec` combined with `regmatches` is good for getting subexpressions (i.e. the stuff in the parentheses).  `regmatches` will return the whole search string and the subexpression, which is why I extract only the second element, which is the subexpression.